# Determinant identity for symmetric 4x4 matrix with zero diagonal

Tags: reference-request, determinant, math-history

Does anybody know a reference or attribution for this identity?
$$
\det
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0          & {a_{12}}^2 & {a_{13}}^2 & {a_{14}}^2 \\
    {a_{12}}^2 & 0          & {a_{23}}^2 & {a_{24}}^2 \\
    {a_{13}}^2 & {a_{23}}^2 & 0          & {a_{34}}^2 \\
    {a_{14}}^2 & {a_{24}}^2 & {a_{34}}^2 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
=\\
(a_{12} a_{34} + a_{13}a_{24} + a_{14} a_{23})
   (a_{12} a_{34} - a_{13}a_{24} - a_{14} a_{23})
     (-a_{12} a_{34} + a_{13}a_{24} - a_{14} a_{23})
     (-a_{12} a_{34} - a_{13}a_{24} + a_{14} a_{23})
$$

I found the related identity
$$
\det
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0          & {a_{12}} & {a_{13}}^2 & {a_{14}}^2 \\
    {a_{12}}^2 & 0          & {a_{23}}^2 & {a_{24}}^2 \\
    {a_{13}}^2 & {a_{23}}^2 & 0          & {a_{34}}^2 \\
    {a_{14}}^2 & {a_{24}}^2 & {a_{34}}^2 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
=
\det
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0          & {a_{12}a_{34}} & {a_{13}a_{24}} & {a_{14}a_{23}} \\
    {a_{12}a_{34}} & 0          & {a_{14}a_{23}} & {a_{13}a_{24}} \\
    {a_{13}a_{24}} & {a_{14}a_{23}} & 0          & {a_{12}a_{34}} \\
    {a_{14}a_{23}} & {a_{13}a_{24}} & {a_{12}a_{34}} & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
in Muir's *Treatise on the Theory of Determinants* (1882), [p. 41](https://archive.org/details/atreatiseontheo00muirgoog/page/n56/mode/2up), but I'm interested in the factorization.

Comment: The determinant of a symmetric $2n\times 2n$-matrix is  a square. Then computing the determinant [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436039/determinant-of-a-symmetric-zero-diagonal-matrix) and using $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+c)$ gives this formula. I don't know if it has a name.

Comment: Checking it is not the problem. I wonder whether it has a name.

Comment: I updated the question for clarity and added history tag. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dehomogenized identity with $\,a_{j4}=1\,$ is [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula#Generalizations) written in terms of a [Cayley–Menger determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant).

$$
\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}
\;=\; \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\,-
  \begin{vmatrix}
    0          & a^2 & b^2 & 1 \\
    a^2 & 0          & c^2 & 1 \\
    b^2 & c^2 & 0          & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0
  \end{vmatrix}}
$$

Comment: Thanks! The factorization part is also in Muir, Exercise 21 on p. 44, and the identity is also in Berger's _Geometry I_, Springer, 1987, p. 424, Example 9.7.3.8.