# Remarkable property of equilateral triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

In a discussion with a math friend and colleague, I was asked to find the angle $APB$ in an equilateral triangle if $AP=3$, $BP=4$ and $CP=5$. In solving this question I rediscovered that the same angle is always found when $a$, $b$ and $c$ satisfy the Pythagorean theorem.

[image]

But I rediscovered another, very surprising theorem.

In an equilateral triangle, the following is true:
$$L^2=\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2{\sqrt{3}}Area_{\triangle _{(PA,PB,PC)}}$$
[image]

I was able to prove this by using two times the cosine rule and expressing $Area_{\triangle _{(PA,PB,PC)}}$ by applying Héron's rule. (And using this theorem, the property mentioned first is easy to prove.)

My question is: is this a known theorem? Does it have a name?

Comment: Can you explain what are $L$ and $Opp_{abc}$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie $L$ is the side length according to the image. I have no idea about $Opp_{abc}$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Don't know what $\,Opp_{abc}\,$ stands for, but the equality implies $\,Opp_{abc} = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\,X\,$ where $X$ is the power of $P$ with respect to the circumcircle.

Comment: @dxiv Nice interpretation of this quantity ! Besides, see my answer for another part of the question.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. That came from $a^2+b^2+c^2=3 PO^2 + L^2$ though I was aware that there must be another geometric connection which I did not immediately see.

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry for using the abbreviation "Opp." for the Dutch word "Oppervlakte" where of course "Area" should have been used.

Answer (score 6):

The wikipedia article about [Pompeiu's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeiu%27s_theorem) mentions this:

> Generally, by the point $P$ and the lengths to the vertices of the equilateral triangle - $PA$, $PB$, and $PC$ two equilateral triangles (the larger and the smaller) with sides $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ are defined:
>
> $$a_{1,2}^{2}={\frac {1}{2}}\left(PA^{2}+PB^{2}+PC^{2}\pm 4{\sqrt{3}}\triangle _{(PA,PB,PC)}\right)$$
>
> The symbol $\triangle$ denotes the area of the triangle whose sides have lengths $PA$, $PB$, $PC$.

Comment: Good catch ! Together with my answer, we give a complete response... but for the angle issue.

Comment: Having establish L from a specified a,b,c, the angle APB is easily found by using the cosine rule in APB. A nice example of such a triangle is by letting $a=1, b=\sqrt{3}$  and c=2 which results in $ L=\sqrt{7}$ and the angles APB, APC and BPC are 150, 120 and 90 degree respectively

Comment: This length relation is also interesting. But I prefer rotating the triangle around a vertex and chasing angles to find the answer to the given problem. No cosine rule; no messy calculations.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, the following figure, copied from the final state of the very nice animation [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/Equilateral345.shtml) explains the connection with pythagorean triples and more generaly with any right triangle :

[image]

The explanations are given in the "cut-the-knot" article for the $3-4-5$ triangle, as you have, but are valid for any right triangle.

---

Edit : A natural question now : let us consider the identity obtained by summing up all the areas of the figure above, knowing that the area of $A'B'C'$ is four times the area of $ABC$ :

With notations $L=AB=AC=BC$, $a=PA,b=PB,c=PC$, and [...] for the areas, we get :

$$[A'B'C'] = \begin{cases} 3 \times [PBP_A]  + & (\text{3 right triangles})\\ [PCP_a]+[PAP_b]+[PBP_c] + & (\text{equilateral triangles})\\
2 \times ([A'P_aB]+[A'P_bC]+[A'P_cA]) & (\text{various triangles})
\end{cases}  $$

Otherwise said :

$$2 \sqrt{3} L^2 = \begin{cases} \frac32 ab + \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(a^2+b^2+c^2) + \\
2 \times \frac14(\delta(L,b,c)+\delta(a,L,c)+\delta(a,b,L))
\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

where $\frac14\delta(x,y,z)$ is the area of a triangle with sides $x,y,z$, that can be expressed under the form :

$$\mathfrak{A}^2=\frac{1}{16}\delta(x,y,z)^2=\frac{1}{16}\begin{vmatrix}
0&1&1&1\\
1&0&x^2&y^2\\
1&x^2&0&z^2\\
1&y^2&z^2&0\end{vmatrix}$$

Besides, we have the relationship given by the Cayley-Menger identity for the mutual distance of 4 points ($A,B,C,P$) in a plane which is :

$$\begin{vmatrix}
0&1&1&1&1\\
1&0&L^2&L^2&a^2\\
1&L^2&0&L^2&b^2\\
1&L^2&L^2&0&c^2\\
1&a^2&b^2&c^2&0\end{vmatrix}=0\tag{2}$$

It is almost evident that (1) and (2) are two faces of a same result, but till now, I have been unable to make a bridge between them...

Comment: About relationship (1) see references [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4392127/305862)

Comment: I also remembered this nice [video](https://youtu.be/dF67AJH9mjM). For a Pythagorean triplet $\angle(x+y)$ is constant.